# Is it possible to use in Python the svm_model, generated in matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, libsvm

Is it possible to use in Python the svm_model, generated in matlab? (I use libsvm)

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just call a method in libsvm to save your model to a file. You then can just use it in Python using their svm.py. So yes, you can - it's all saved in libsvm format.